# A href tag not working

Tags: html

I am creating download links to PDFs of Chinese articles I have written, but for some reason, the links are not working. I stopped at the first li because I could not figure it out. Even when I change it to a simple a href to my home page, it still does not work.

```
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chinese.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yellowtail" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script> 
<script src="Chinese.js"></script>

    <div class="samples">
        <li><a href="XiJinPing.pdf" download>習近平反貪</a></li>
        <li>伊波拉與伊斯蘭國：世界末日的徵兆</li>
        <li>人類是否應探索太空?</li>
        <li>社會的價值觀與同性戀</li>
        <li>兩岸的未來</li>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to render ok? https://jsfiddle.net/p1p4gcy2/

Comment: is this in the `<body>` or the `<head>`? if it's in the head, obviously you need to put it in the body. if it's in the body, obviously you need to put your `<link>` tags  in the head.

Comment: Link tags and script tags are in the head, the div is in the body. It works on the jsfiddle (as in it is at least clickable) but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I thought you meant the links to the files were not working. (Which is why I suggested the following)

The download attribute is not supported in IE or Safari. Which browser are you using? Do you get an error message? Make sure your XiJinPing.pdf file is in the same directory as the HTML file.

Is the source actually being served or just opened in the browser?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Now that I have re-read the question it appears that you mean the link tags are not working. 
The first CSS (shift.css) only adds a font-face to know if it works you will need to add that font-face to an item through a style.

```
div {
  font-family: Shift;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/6wvjbk07/8/)

The second thing you need to do is add the javascript for bootstrap.

Also if you run into Cross Scripting errors, you may need to use HTTPS versions of the links to your css files or vice versa. Chrome blocks traffic automatically but a shield will show up in the address bar and you can select it to allow the traffic anyway.

You should also close the link tags.

Comment: I am using Chrome. Perhaps it has something do to with my includes?

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: also, according to your link, it's only supported in newer browsers. chrome 14+, etc..

Comment: Hopefully Will has updated chrome since 2011-09-16
[Chrome Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history)